# Python Chord Diagram (Plotly) - Interactive Tooltips

Tags: python, plotly

I followed the guide here:

https://plot.ly/python/filled-chord-diagram/

And I produced this:

[image]

In the guide, I followed the `ribbon_info` code to add hoverinfo to the connecting ribbons but nothing shows. I can get the hoverinfo to only show for the ribbon ends. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
ribbon_info=[]
for k in range(L):

    sigma=idx_sort[k]
    sigma_inv=invPerm(sigma)
    for j in range(k, L):
        if matrix[k][j]==0 and matrix[j][k]==0: continue
        eta=idx_sort[j]
        eta_inv=invPerm(eta)
        l=ribbon_ends[k][sigma_inv[j]]  

        if j==k:
            layout['shapes'].append(make_self_rel(l, 'rgb(175,175,175)' ,
                                    ideo_colors[k], radius=radii_sribb[k]))
            z=0.9*np.exp(1j*(l[0]+l[1])/2)
            #the text below will be displayed when hovering the mouse over the ribbon
            text=labels[k]+' appears on'+ '{:d}'.format(matrix[k][k])+' of the same grants as  '+ '',
            ribbon_info.append(Scatter(x=z.real,
                                       y=z.imag,
                                       mode='markers',
                                       marker=Marker(size=5, color=ideo_colors[k]),
                                       text=text,
                                       hoverinfo='text'
                                       )
                              )
        else:
            r=ribbon_ends[j][eta_inv[k]]
            zi=0.9*np.exp(1j*(l[0]+l[1])/2)
            zf=0.9*np.exp(1j*(r[0]+r[1])/2)
            #texti and textf are the strings that will be displayed when hovering the mouse 
            #over the two ribbon ends
            texti=labels[k]+' appears on '+ '{:d}'.format(matrix[k][j])+' of the same grants as '+\
                  labels[j]+ '',

            textf=labels[j]+' appears on '+ '{:d}'.format(matrix[j][k])+' of the same grants as '+\
                  labels[k]+ '',
            ribbon_info.append(Scatter(x=zi.real,
                                       y=zi.imag,
                                       mode='markers',
                                       marker=Marker(size=0.5, color=ribbon_color[k][j]),
                                       text=texti,
                                       hoverinfo='text'
                                       )
                              ),
            ribbon_info.append(Scatter(x=zf.real,
                                       y=zf.imag,
                                       mode='markers',
                                       marker=Marker(size=0.5, color=ribbon_color[k][j]),
                                       text=textf,
                                       hoverinfo='text'
                                       )
                              )
            r=(r[1], r[0])#IMPORTANT!!!  Reverse these arc ends because otherwise you get
                          # a twisted ribbon
            #append the ribbon shape
            layout['shapes'].append(make_ribbon(l, r , 'rgb(255,175,175)', ribbon_color[k][j]))
```

The outputs for the variables are as follows:

```
texti = (u'Sociology appears on 79 of the same grants as Tools, technologies & methods',)

textf = (u'Tools, technologies & methods appears on 79 of the same grants as Sociology',)

ribbon_info = [{'hoverinfo': 'text',
  'marker': {'color': 'rgba(214, 248, 149, 0.65)', 'size': 0.5},
  'mode': 'markers',
  'text': (u'Demography appears on 51 of the same grants as Social policy',),
  'type': 'scatter',
  'x': 0.89904409911342476,
  'y': 0.04146936036799545},
 {'hoverinfo': 'text',
  'marker': {'color': 'rgba(214, 248, 149, 0.65)', 'size': 0.5},
  'mode': 'markers',
  'text': (u'Social policy appears on 51 of the same grants as Demography',),
  'type': 'scatter',
  'x': -0.65713108202353809,
  'y': -0.61496238993825791},..................**etc**

sigma = array([ 0, 14, 12, 10,  9,  7,  8,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  6, 16, 13, 11, 15], dtype=int64)
```

The code after the previous block which builds the chord diagram is as follows:

```
ideograms=[]
for k in range(len(ideo_ends)):
    z= make_ideogram_arc(1.1, ideo_ends[k])
    zi=make_ideogram_arc(1.0, ideo_ends[k])
    m=len(z)
    n=len(zi)
    ideograms.append(Scatter(x=z.real,
                             y=z.imag,
                             mode='lines',
                             line=Line(color=ideo_colors[k], shape='spline', width=0),
                             text=labels[k]+'<br>'+'{:d}'.format(row_sum[k]), 
                             hoverinfo='text'
                             )
                     )


    path='M '
    for s in range(m):
        path+=str(z.real[s])+', '+str(z.imag[s])+' L '

    Zi=np.array(zi.tolist()[::-1]) 

    for s in range(m):
        path+=str(Zi.real[s])+', '+str(Zi.imag[s])+' L '
    path+=str(z.real[0])+' ,'+str(z.imag[0]) 

    layout['shapes'].append(make_ideo_shape(path,'rgb(150,150,150)' , ideo_colors[k]))

data = Data(ideograms+ribbon_info)
fig=Figure(data=data, layout=layout) 

plotly.offline.iplot(fig, filename='chord-diagram-Fb')
```

This is the only hoverinfo that shows, the outside labels, not the ones just slightly more inside:

[image]

Using the example from the link at the start of my question. They have two sets of labels. On my example, the equivalent of 'Isabelle has commented on 32 of Sophia....' is not showing.

[image]

Comment: From the provided link: "ribbon_info is a list of dicts setting the information that is displayed when hovering the mouse over the ribbon ends." Plotly only allows hoverinfo for markers, not for the connecting lines.

Comment: So when ribbon_info appends textf and texti, what is it doing as the ribbon ends on my graph only show the labels i.e. 'Economics'. In the very bottom of the link I had at the start of my question (https://plot.ly/python/filled-chord-diagram/) their chart has labels on the ribbon ends AND on the ribbons? :/

Comment: My browser shows hoverinfo when the cursor is at the outer part of the circle but not inside. In addition there is some hoverinfo close to the outer segment but again, nothing inside. Remove `class="shapelayer"` in your browser to get rid of the ribbons and see the underlying markers which trigger the hoverinfo.

Comment: Ill turn on my work computer now and will give it a go. Thank you! Ill be back :)

Comment: So it has a marker of: "mode": "markers", "hoverinfo": "text", "y": 0.24497006996652776, "x": -0.8660194367452698, "type": "scatter"}, {"text": ["Development studies appears on 66 of the same grants as Social policy"], "marker": {"color": "rgba(248, 212, 141, 0.65)", "size": 0.5},....... for one of them, but it isnt showing, is it because -0.86 is outside of the chart range? There are some markers with positive numbers, so maybe that isnt it

Comment: Ive added an additional screenshot to the question to show you the labels that are showing. Its the other ones that are slightly below it which are not :)

Comment: Thanks! That really clarifies the scope of the question. Showing labels completely inside the circle is a mess but the other ones should be doable.

Comment: Ive added another picture of the linked example. So I can get 'Isabella' to show, but I cant get 'Isabella commented on 32....' to show, which is slightly more in the circle than the 'Isabella' label

Comment: Also, the labels are appended to the ideogram (they work), it is the ribbon_info that is causing issues despite all the text being in it if I call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for chord diagram generation was posted by Plotly two years ago. Meanwhile a few changes were performed in the definition of Plotly shapes. To make tooltips work in offline mode you should:

1) insert the line

```
layer='below'
```

in the returned dicts by the functions `make_ideo_shape`, `make_ribbon`, `make_self_rel`;

2) In the cell that contains the definition of the list `ribbon_info`, change on each of the three lines containing `ribbon_info.append`, the x, and y assigned values, to lists containing those values:

```
x=[z.real],
y=[z.imag],

x=[zi.real],
y=[zi.imag],
```

respectively,

```
x=[zf.real],
y=[zf.imag],
```

The corresponding notebook https://plot.ly/python/filled-chord-diagram/ is  updated now.
Thanks to Python StackOverflow @PythonStack for pointing  out this bug, here: https://twitter.com/PythonStack/status/914924595953721344

Comment: That is really helpful. Thank you so much for responding on my post! Especially given its age

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. It turns out the ribbon_info does not like being run offline, as soon as I did it online it showed. I.e. it does not run in plotly.offline. You HAVE to do it online

Edit: not sure why downvoted, a lot of people use plotly offline. Hope this helps!