# How can I make a chord diagram using python?

Tags: python, visualization, chord-diagram

I have a small dataset indicating flows in-between zones. I want to create a chord diagram, and each chord's width being proportional to its value.

My dataset is the following:

```
# Given data
data = {
    'Unnamed: 0': ['North', 'Center', 'South'],
    'North': [50, 100, 150],
    'Center': [20, 80, 160],
    'South': [70, 150, 230]
}
```

```
# Create a DataFrame and set 'Unnamed: 0' as the index
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('Unnamed: 0')
```

```
# Transpose the DataFrame to get a square matrix
df = df.transpose()
```

So far I have tried using the library of the D3Blocks:

```
from d3blocks import D3Blocks
# Convert the DataFrame to the required format for d3blocks
df_reset = df.reset_index()
df_melted = pd.melt(df_reset, id_vars='index', var_name='target', value_name='weight')
df_melted = df_melted.rename(columns={'index': 'source'})

# Initialize d3blocks
d3 = D3Blocks()

# Plot the chord diagram
d3.chord(df_melted)
```

The code works. However, I cannot adjust the width of the chords connecting the zones based on their value as it is nicely done for other cases ([Circular Chord Diagram in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65344303/circular-chord-diagram-in-python)).
[image]

I also found another solution by using the PlotAPI (https://plotapi.com/), but it seems it is no longer for free.

Can you help me with making the chord diagram I need? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My top Duck Duck Go hit is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191793/python-chord-diagram-plotly-interactive-tooltips but I am not familiar enough with the library or the diagram type to tell whether it supports what you want. Probably try to come up with a more specific title?